# Match position of two divs with similar id (#thumb-1 == #project-1) in JavaScript/jQuery not jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, match

I am building a portfolio gallery, with the following html:

```
<article class="work-gallery">
        <ul>
            <li id="project-1"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x00"></li>            
            <li id="project-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></li>
            <li id="project-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></li>           
        </ul>
</article>
        <div class="projects">
            <div id="detail-1" class="project-content project-1">Test</div>
            <div id="detail-2" class="project-content project-2">Test</div>
            <div id="detail-3" class="project-content project-3">Test</div>            
        </div><!-- end .projects -->
```

What I'd like to do when the page loads, is set #detail-1 to match the x/y coordinates of #project-1, #detail-2 of #project-2, etc.

Here's the code that I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var thumb = $('.work-gallery li'),
        thumbId = thumb.attr('id'),
        thumbIdNumber = thumbId.substring(thumbId.indexOf('-') + 1, thumbId.length),
        thumbProject = $('#detail-' + thumbIdNumber);
    thumbProject.css({'top': thumb.position.top});
});
```

... but in the last statement I'm not specifying the id of the thumb variable. So that's where I'm stuck. If anyone has other suggestions as to how this can be done, or alternative ways to do it, I'd be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this would work fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.work-gallery li').each(function(){
        var elem = $(this),
            thumbId = elem.attr('id');
        $('#detail-' + thumbId.split('-')[1]).css({top: elem.position().top});
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Taxellool/D2BSy/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Taxellool - I think it looks good and the logic makes a lot of sense - however, I get a typeError: thumbId is undefined.

Comment: @TitusBartos I just tested it and got no error. it wasn't working properly but it was because of elem.position.top, not for thumbId. 
Anyway I updated the answer and added a fiddle.

Comment: thank you again, the code works perfectly. Not sure why, but I still get the same thumbId is undefined error.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle by exact code that you are running?